# How to connect to a Windows GIT repository from Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: git, ubuntu, smb

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and have a VPN connection to a windows network with a GIT reposiotry. I can access the repository via

```
smb://192.168.1.71/users/Git/myrepo.git
```

but GIT doesn't support the smb protocol. From the git manual

> The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
> ```
> ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
> [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
> ```

So the following does not work

```
git remote set-url origin smb://192.168.1.71/users/Git/myrepo.git
```

What is a good workaround?

Comment: As it’s an Ubuntu distribution why not use ssh?

Answer (score 2):

mount the repository via

1. `mkdir /mnt/windowsgit`
2. `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`
3. `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.71/users/Git /mnt/windowsgit -o user=USERNAME`

where `cifs-utils` are required to mount a smb location and the `USERNAME` is the username required for the windows network. You will be asked for a password.

To work with myrepo.git use

```
git remote set-url origin file://mnt/windowsgit/myrepo.git
```

and use

```
sudo git pull
sudo git push
```

since `/mnt/` requires sudo rights.

you may get

> fatal: '\192.168.1.71\Users\Git\myrepo.git' does not appear to be a
>   git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

after the usual git messages, and I dont know why, but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount the repisotiry to the real filesystem with smbmount
2. run the anonymous git-daemon at windows
3. set up sshd at windows side
4. set up IIS at windows side, and export the repository as dumb http
5. set up IIS at windows site, and set up cgi which runs "git http-backend"